# How do I detect touches anywhere on the screen of a tableview, not just the cell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, fullscreen

I would like to hide the navigation bar, status bar, and tab bar when a user taps anywhere on the screen.  The view for this tab is a tableview but the cells are inactive (they store images and text and do not perform any actions).

Is there a method for detecting touches on the screen of a tableview?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I ended up just using didSelectRowAtIndexPath to activate the appropriate action. It just became too complicated to make a selection anywhere on the screen work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm at work so I can't verify this, but UITableView is a subclass of UIResponder. You should be able subclass UITableView and override -touchesEnded:withEvent: and do whatever you want from there.

Hope that helps.